# Можно ли привести объект одного типа в другой тип, если поля их классов совпадают?

Tags: c#

При попытке присвоить коллекции с типом Answer коллекцию с типом CAnswer возникает ошибка.
Код:

```cs
List<Question> json = new();
List<Answer> answers= new();
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)
{
    foreach(CAnswer ans in myCollection[i].CAnswers)
    {
        answers = ans;
    }
}
```

Вот код первого класса:

```cs
public class Answer
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот второго:

```cs
public class CAnswer
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: В теории можно. Например, сериализовать и десериализовать. Или чутка вникруть в указатели и через небезопасный код попробовать. Но вам это наверняка не нужно. Если вы столкнулись с такой задачей, то вы с большой вероятностью делаете что то не так.

Comment: Сделать общий интерфейс? `IAnswer`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо, помогло